# Can you still Target Allies with a spell if you have the Status Spell in effect and are blinded?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, targeting

I was wondering if you could target an ally while being [blinded](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:blinded) if you had the [Status](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Status) spell on them.

> #### Status
>
> When you need to keep track of comrades who may get separated, status allows you to mentally monitor their relative positions and general condition. You are aware of direction and distance to the creatures and any conditions affecting them: unharmed, wounded, disabled, staggered, unconscious, dying, nauseated, panicked, stunned, poisoned, diseased, confused, or the like. Once the spell has been cast upon the subjects, the distance between them and the caster does not affect the spell as long as they are on the same plane of existence. If a subject leaves the plane, or if it dies, the spell ceases to function for it.

Can you for example cast [Heal](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Heal) (with the [Reach Spell](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Reach_Spell) metamagic feat) or [Remove Fear](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Remove_Fear) on them?

Answer (score 6):

**Strictly RAW, yes, sometimes**

The description for the condition Blinded, as you have linked, states (emphasis mine):

> Unable to see...  All checks and activities that rely on vision (such
>   as reading and Spot checks) automatically fail.  All *opponents* are
>   considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) relative to the
>   blinded character.

Your allies are not opponents, so they do not have total concealment.  So you still need to succeed on a ranged touch attack roll to hit your ally to cast (Reach) Heal (as Reach Spells are treated as rays), with Status definitely letting you know which way to aim, but by RAW you do not suffer the 50% miss chance.

Exploring targeted spells - touch spells can be delivered to allies even without Status.  However, while blinded you can only cast Remove Fear on allies that you are touching.  This is because the spell selects particular Target or Targets but is *not* a ray spell.  Under the rules for Aiming a Spell on p175 of PHB:

> **Target or Targets:**  ...You must be able to *see* or touch the target, and you must specifically
>   choose that target.

The Status spell does not let you see your allies, so by RAW you cannot cast targeted spells on them.

Comment: Yes, and under RAI allies of blinded character still would have total concealment - it's the only, and quite reasonable, difference.